# jQuery being ignored only on iOS 4.2.1

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari

Is there anything radically different with iOS 4.2.1 vs. previous and newer versions of iOS with regard to JavaScript?

I am testing a site and on every browser and device I test the jQuery is working fine, but it's being completely ignored in iOS 4.2.1 on my iPod Touch test device.

I can provide code examples if need be. I am using the following:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to enable the debug mode?

Comment: Yes, it shows the following error as soon as it hits the jquery code: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $. All other browsers I've tested don't have javascript errors in their consoles.

Comment: Do you have internet access? have you tried loading a local jquery?

Comment: yes, the device is hitting the internet fine and I tried pulling the files down and loading locally, but that didn't help. I don't know exactly what is different with this device, but it's the only one I am running into issues on.

Comment: Can you provide some of your source code? there may be something around your include that is failing.  e.g. if you omit a closing `</script>` tag on **any** of your script tags you **may** get errors in some browsers.

Comment: Are you using jQuery.noConflict()? If so the $ becomes unavailable

Comment: I'm not using .noConflict(). Sorry for the delay posting code. I am trying to create a stripped down test page on my end before posting the code up here. Right now, it has a bunch of client info in it.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding the issue in this particular case. I had a lot of code to strip away, so I set up a test page with nothing but my jquery calls and the most basic jquery alert function.

It turns out out it was a difference between http and http**s**. As soon as I removed the "s", the reference error went away in the debug console.

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem just now:

I like to now use this style of importing scripts

src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"

notice the // if the page loading the script is https it will do https otherwise http